# Single file merge in Subversion

Tags: svn

I'm using Subversion 1.5 and have a single file in a branch that I want to merge into another branch. When I do a `svn merge http://path/to/file` I get an error,

> Cannot replace a directory from with .

Does this just mean that Subversion can't do this?

Answer (score 74):

Try specifying the path to the local file as well.

For example,

```
svn merge -r1234:1235 svn://your_svn_url/to/file ./local_file
```

Comment: I've heard that merging using SVN 1.5 and before is very different, but this was a very helpful answer for merging with SVN 1.6 as well.

Comment: What if this is a new file, so there is no "./local_file" you can pass?

Comment: @MarcGlisse The two files must have a common ancestry, so it's impossible to merge a new file. What you can do instead is make a copy of the remote file with `svn cp svn://your_svn_url/to/file ./local_file` and then modify or locally patch the file.

Answer (score 4):

Im am using subversion 1.8.8 and

```
svn merge ^/trunk/path_to_file ./branch/path_to_local_file
```

works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

The merge, as Andrew recommended it, worked for me, but not for every file. I had three files, but for the third I got the error "...path not found". Adding the argument " --ignore-ancestry" solved that problem.

But after merging I had strange modified/merged file status and a lot of `svn:mergeinfo` added to my working copy.

So I decided to just do a simple copy&paste for single files to avoid such confusing stuff until we switch to Git where these tasks are really no problem at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do a

```
svn merge http://server/repos/path/to -r <REV>
```

where <REV> is the revision where the file was added. That way merge information is recorded (in case of a Subversion 1.5 or higher repository).