# svn merge individual files. Add new file

Tags: linux, svn, centos

I am trying to merge individual files between two branches . All is well except for newly added files in source branch .

how can I merge newly added files from source to target .

```
svn merge -c123 https://my.svn.domain/svn/foo/branches/bar/newfile.txt ./newfile.txt
svn: E200009: Merge target './newfile.txt' does not exist in the working copy
```

EDIT 1: 
I am using svn version 1.7.19

EDIT 2: Getting this error while trying to merge a file with status "A" .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single file merge in Subversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616752/single-file-merge-in-subversion)

Comment: svn merge ^/trunk/path_to_file ./branch/path_to_local_file refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/616752/single-file-merge-in-subversion

Comment: I seem to be doing the same thing as in Andrews's answer . Getting the error svn: E200009: Merge target './newfile.txt' does not exist in the working copy

Answer (score 0):

To merge individual file  you should confirm the target file exist then use the command like :

```
$ svn merge -c 31 ^/brunchs/xxxx  xxxx
```

Comment: Pleas see EDIT 2 in my question